# jquery each input multiple quantity calculation got NaN in dynamic form

Tags: php, jquery

I cannot found where is the issue with my code, in another topic ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266543/jquery-form-each-input-accept-only-multiple-values)) I got help to made calculation of multiple quantities from box products, and it's work well. But when I adapt the help to my main code something is not working wright. Basically the problem is, when run the code separate ok, but when I run in my code the quantity of package returns as NaN. I'll send a screen for help what I've been for.

[image]

My issue is here:

```
$(".ItemQtd").each(function() {
    var number = parseInt( $(this).val() );
    var package = parseInt( $(this).next(".ItemEmb").val() );

    if (number % package === 0) {
      alert(`${number} is multiple of ${package}.`);
    } else {
      alert(`${number} is not multiple of ${package}.`);
    }
  });
```

Here is my full code:

```
<?php
//index.php

$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$ipad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$symbian = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Symbian");
$windowsphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Windows Phone");

if ($iphone || $ipad || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry || $symbian || $windowsphone == true) {
   $dispositivo = "mobile";
 }

else { $dispositivo = "computador";} 

//Se for um dispositivo móvel
if ($dispositivo == "mobile") {
  header("Location: mobile/");
}

//Se for um computador
if ($dispositivo == "computador") {
  //Não faz nada
}


require_once("conexao.php");
//Desconto lista
function fill_unit_select_box($pdo)
{ 
 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_desc ORDER BY IdDesc ASC";
 $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row["DescName"].'">'.$row["DescName"].'</option>';
 }
 return $output;
}

//Produto lista
function fill_prod_select_box($pdo)
{ 
 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_prod ORDER BY ItemName ASC";
 $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row["ItemCode"].'">'.$row["ItemCode"].'</option>';
 }
 return $output;
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Pedidos</title>

  <!-- JS jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" ></script>
<!--    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> -->

  <!-- CSS Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/icons/css/coreui-icons.min.css">
  <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- JS -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Personal Style -->
  <style>.invertcores{filter: invert(100%);}</style>  

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jautocalc.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>

  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <form method="post" id="insert_form" name="cart">
    Total do Pedido
    <input type="text" name="sub_total" class="form-control col-2"  jAutoCalc="SUM({.soma})" readonly>
    <hr>

    <button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success add">Adicionar Linha</button>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Gravar Pedido" />
    <input type="button" name="reset" class="text-white btn btn-secondary reset" value="Restaurar" />

    <br><br>
    <div class="table-responsive">
     <span id="error"></span>
     <table class="table" id="item_table" name="cart">
      <tr>
        <th width="14%">Cód. Produto</th>
        <th width="40%">Descrição do Produto</th>
        <th width="5%">Quantidade</th>
        <th width="7.5%">Unid.</th>
        <th width="7%">Emb.</th>
        <th width="2%">Caixas</th>
        <th width="8%">Preço(R$)</th>
        <th width="10%">Total(R$)</th>
        <th width="8.5%">Desconto</th>
        <th>Ações</th>
      </tr>
      <tr name="line_items">
        <td><select class="form-control ItemCode" name="ItemCode[]"><option value="">Selecionar</option><?php echo fill_prod_select_box($pdo); ?></select></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ItemName[]" class="form-control ItemName text-break text-uppercase" value="Descrição 316" readonly/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ItemQtd[]" class="form-control ItemQtd" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ItemUnit[]" class="form-control ItemUnit" value="PÇ" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ItemEmb[]" class="form-control ItemEmb" value="50" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control ItemCx"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Price[]" class="form-control ItemPrice" value="0,95" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="LineTotal[]" class="form-control LineTotal2 soma dinheiro" jAutoCalc="{.ItemQtd} * {.ItemPrice}" /></td>
        <td><select name="ItemDesc[]" class="form-control ItemDesc"><option value="">Selecionar</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($pdo); ?></select></td>
        <td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><img class="invertcores" src="icons/x.svg"></button></td>
      </tr>


     </table>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<!--///////////////////////////////////////////#Script do Form///////////////////////////////////////////////-->

<script>

//
$(document).ready(function() {

      function autoCalcSetup() {
          $('form[name=cart]').jAutoCalc('destroy');
          $('form[name=cart] tr[name=line_items]').jAutoCalc({keyEventsFire: true, decimalPlaces: 2, emptyAsZero: true});
          $('form[name=cart]').jAutoCalc({decimalPlaces: 2});
         }
        autoCalcSetup();

      $('button[name=remove]').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          var form = $(this).parents('form')
          $(this).parents('tr').remove();
          autoCalcSetup();

      });

      $('button[name=add]').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          var $table = $(this).parents('form');
          var $top = $table.find('tr[name=line_items]').last();
          var $new = $top.clone(true);

          $new.jAutoCalc('destroy');
          $new.insertAfter($top);
          $new.find('input[type=text]').val('');
          autoCalcSetup();

      });

//Remover linha
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});

//Reload da página
$(document).on('click', '.reset', function(){
  swal({
    //"Click on either the button or outside the modal."
    title: "Atenção!",
    text: "Você deseja realmente recarregar e perder todo o conteúdo?",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
    //button: "Sim",
    buttons: ["Não", "Sim"],
    })
    .then((willDelete) => {
      if (willDelete) {
        swal("Pronto! Todos os itens foram restaurados!", {
          icon: "success",
        })
        .then((value) => {
          location.reload();
        });
      } else {
        swal("Nenhuma alteração foi realizada!", {icon: "info",});
      }
    });
 });

 //Enviar itens para o banco
 $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var error = '';
  $('.ItemCode').each(function(){
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>* Inserir o código do item na linha faltante</p>";
      return false;
   }
  });


  $(".ItemQtd").each(function() {
    var number = parseInt( $(this).val() );
    var package = parseInt( $(this).next(".ItemEmb").val() );

    if (number % package === 0) {
      alert(`${number} is multiple of ${package}.`);
    } else {
      alert(`${number} is not multiple of ${package}.`);
    }
  });

  $('.ItemDesc').each(function(){
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>* Selecione o desconto na linha faltante</p>";
      return false;
   }
  });

  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  if(error == '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data)
    {
     if(data == 'ok')
     {
      //location.reload();
      /*setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload(1);
      }, 3000); */ // 3 segundos
      swal({
        //"Click on either the button or outside the modal."
        title: "Concluído!",
        text: "Você adicionou o pedido com sucesso!",
        icon: "success",
        button: "Voltar",
        })
      .then((value) => {
        $('#item_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        location.reload();
        //swal(`The returned value is: ${value}`);
      });
      //swal("Concluído!", "Você adicionou o pedido com sucesso!", "success");
      //$('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Pedido gravado com sucesso</div>');
      //alert(data);
     }
   //document.location.assign('success.php'); //redirecionar para alguma página
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {

    swal({
      title: "Atenção!",
      text: "Você não preencheu algum campo necessário!",
      icon: "error",
      button: "Voltar",
    })
    .then((value) => {
      $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible show" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><strong>Atenção!</strong>'+error+'</div>');
      });
  }

 });

});

</script>
```

Comment: if some number got empty then you will got NaN, so check that you got some data from input.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra the problem is that input field is filled, the Emb. column is the number in question to made the calc, and the code supposed to show instead NaN number 50 and after 20 as the values. So I can't understand if I had values inside why still I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your *My issue is here*: code with below

```
$(".ItemQtd").each(function() {

  if($(this).val() &&  $(this).next(".ItemEmb").val()){

      var number = parseInt( $(this).val() );
      var package = parseInt( $(this).next(".ItemEmb").val() );

      if (number % package === 0) {
        alert(`${number} is multiple of ${package}.`);
      } else {
        alert(`${number} is not multiple of ${package}.`);
      }
  }
```

Comment: I changed as you said and add close signal " });" but now I got nothing alert instead.

Comment: it means that you did not get any value from  `$(this).val()` and   `$(this).next(".ItemEmb").val()`

Comment: But how is it possible? I typed the values inside input

Comment: I check the class and found the error, the reference was into a empty input. Thanks!